# how to check dynamically if user hasn't deleted value from textarea

Tags: javascript, html

I want to make buttons enable when all textboxes have values and radiobutton is checked.

It works, as long as I don't try to delete some values. Then one of textboxes is empty but buttons are still enable, while I want them to be disable. how to change it?

```
<body>
    <h2>@ViewBag.Title.</h2>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <section>
            @using (Html.BeginForm("Add", "Question", new {ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl}, FormMethod.Post, new {@class = "form-horizontal", role = "form"}))
            {
                @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                <h4>//</h4>
                <hr/>
                @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new {@class = "text-danger"})

                        @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.QuestionContent, new {@class = "form-control", @rows = "7", @cols = "50", @id= "a", @type = "textarea" })

                        @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.AnswerA, new {@class = "form-control", @rows = "7", @cols = "50", @style = "margin-top: 15px", @id = "a", @type = "input" })




    @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.AnswerC, new {@class = "form-control", @rows = "7", @cols = "50", @style = "margin-top: 15px",@id = "a", @type = "input" })

                            @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.AnswerD, new {@class = "form-control", @rows = "7", @cols = "50", @style = "margin-top: 15px; margin-bottom: 30px", @id = "a", @type = "input" })

                        @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.CorrectAnswer, "a", new {@type="radio"})

                        @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.CorrectAnswer, "b", new { @type = "radio" })

                        @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.CorrectAnswer, "c", new { @type = "radio" })

                        @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.CorrectAnswer, "d", new { @type = "radio" })

                                <input id="addNewQuestion" type="submit" value="Dodaj nowe pytanie" class="btn btn-default" style="margin-top: 30px; margin-left: -80px !important"/>
                                <input id="finish" type="submit" name="AddAndFinish" value="Zakończ dodawanie testu" formaction="AddAndFinish" class="btn btn-default" style="margin-top: 30px; margin-left: 10px !important"/>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                }
            </section>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {

            $('input[type="submit"]').attr('disabled', true);

            $('input[type="text"],textarea').on('keyup', function () {

                var questionContentValue = $("#questionContentArea").val();
                var answerAValue = $('input[name="ans_a"]').val();
                var answerBValue = $('input[name="ans_b"]').val();
                var answerCValue = $('input[name="ans_c"]').val();
                var answerDValue = $('input[name="ans_d"]').val();

                var clicked = false;

                $('[type="radio"]').change(function() {

                    clicked = true;

                if ((questionContentValue != '') && (answerAValue != '') && (answerBValue != '') && (answerCValue != '') && (answerDValue != '')&& clicked == true) {

                        $('input[type="submit"]').attr('disabled', false);

                } else {
                    $('input[type="submit"]').attr('disabled', true);
                }
            });
            });
        });

    </script>
    </body>

There're also other stufs in code to make my html look good, but they're not important.
```

Comment: don't nest event listeners inside other event handlers. Keep them separate. In your case every keyup will create a new change listener and the previous ones will still exist and no event listener on radio will exist unto a keyup occurs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will work for you. I've updated it to include radio buttons and closer match your example's selectors and what you're doing. This might be more straightforward for you to incorporate into your `document ready()` function.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Testing</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function disableButtons() {
        $("input[type='submit']").attr("disabled", true);
    }

    function enableButtons() {
        $("input[type='submit']").attr("disabled", false);
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {
        //start with buttons disabled.
        disableButtons();

        var $textInputs = $('input[type="text"],textarea');

        //when any inputs/textareas change, re-evaluate all inputs and toggle buttons appropriately
        $('input,textarea').on('change', function() {
            //filter text inputs to the empty ones and see if there are any
            var anyEmpty = $textInputs.filter(function() { return this.value == ""; }).length > 0;
            //see if any radio buttons are selected
            var anyClicked = $('input[type="radio"]:checked').length > 0;
            if (!anyEmpty && anyClicked) {
                enableButtons();
            } else {
                disableButtons();
            }
        });
    });
</script>
</head>

<body>
    <div><input type="text" name="input1" value="" class="input"></div>
    <div><input type="text" name="input2" value="" class="input"></div>
    <div><textarea name="input3" rows="8" cols="80" class="input"></textarea></div>
    <div>
        <input type="radio" name="radioInput" value="Radio 1">
        <input type="radio" name="radioInput" value="Radio 2">
    </div>

    <div class="buttons">
        <input type="submit" name="button1" class="button" value="Submit 1" />
        <input type="submit" name="button2" class="button" value="Submit2" />
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Updated my answer to be more complete. Disabling the button initially. Enabling and disabling the buttons as the inputs become empty or all have values.

Comment: I'm doing something wrong because now it doesn't work at all

Comment: If you save my example to an html file you're saying my example doesn't work for you? Or when you try to incorporate it into your code it's not working? You'll have to change the jquery selectors, etc to match your stuff. If you update your code example in your post I can try and help spot any trouble.

Comment: I think my latest updates should match your example pretty well. Hopefully you can use my javascript in place of yours without much modification necessary? At least based on my understanding of the html you're rendering.